# RxJS - managing an array of expiring observables

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to implement a notification widget.
Every now and then, a message (a "toast") will be displayed in a corner of the browser window.
I would like to have the message auto-hide after, say, 30 seconds.
What I would also like is that, if more messages arrive in the meantime, the widget will display each one over the other, in a stack, progressively hiding the expiring messages.

I could implement everything with just `setTimeout`, but I'm pretty sure RxJS can make use of a nicer approach, and I find the documentation very difficult to navigate. (I'm struggling with http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html, http://rxmarbles.com/, blog posts etc etc)

Does anyone know of one or more operators that could help in fulfilling the requirement?

Thanks!

Edit: an example timeline

```
0 - empty window
1 - show "A"
5 - show "B" (A and B are both shown)
29 -  show "C" (A, B and C are stacked)
31 - A disappears (only B and C remain)
35 - B disappears (C shown)
59 - C disappears
```

Comment: If 5 messages come really quickly do you want to quickly cycle through each one (in which case you might not see the first 4) or display each one for 30 seconds? (in which case it takes 2.5 minutes to show all 5)

Comment: I want to stack them: I'll generate 5 toast elements, stacked top to bottom from the first arrived to the last, each one disappearing after independently 30 seconds after their arrival.

Comment: Assuming you have already a toaster library in place, this needs nothing fanciful. Just subscribe to your notification source, and let the library do the rest aka set the library option to dismiss the notification after x seconds. If not, just use a `.delay()` operator in place of your `setTimeout`

Comment: Without the code a) it's not easy to understand what you have and what's not working; b) you're basically asking to solve a problem for you.

Comment: @Igor: as for (a), sorry, I know. But there is no code. As for (b), no: I'm asking for pointers to the myriad of operators in RxJS. Everyone is SO is "asking to solve problems" in some way. May I feel lost in  front of something like this ? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html Or should I know RxJS by heart before asking questions?

Comment: @CozyAzure: thanks. I was just wondering if something more elegant come s to mind. I'm exploring RxJS (it's so HUGE!) and I constantly stumble upon operators that seem to be designed to solve specific problems. I was wondering if something more specific comes to mind.

Comment: @CozyAzure: and, I don't have a toast library. I'm on Angular and given the (apparent) simplicity of the task, I was wondering if I can implement my own (I have to adapt the UI anyway).

Answer (score 3):

You can use subject as a queue  to  push toaster to it. delay() lets you adjust the duration of toaster staying on screen

```
let a=Rx.Observable.of('a')
let b=Rx.Observable.of('b')
let c=Rx.Observable.of('c')

let queue=new Rx.Subject()


queue.mergeMap(res=>res)
.do(res=>{
// you can make toast appear now
console.log(res,':appearing')
})
.delay(2000)
.do(res=>{
// you can make toast disappear now
console.log(res,':disappearing')
}).subscribe()

setTimeout(()=>queue.next(a))
setTimeout(()=>queue.next(b),2000)
setTimeout(()=>queue.next(c),4000)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7jcsLd4o/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the kind of operator I was looking for: the `scan` operator (documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) and [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html)).

I based my implementation on a `Subject` emitting "hide" and "show" events, and on a `BehaviourSubject` accumulating the events onto an array.

The elements relevant for RxJS are as follows:

```
export class Message {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  type: MessageType;
}

export class MessageAction {
  action: 'show' | 'hide';
  msg: Message;
}

...
export class NotificationComponent {
...

  messages = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>([]);
  msgsSource = new Subject<MessageAction>();


  constructor() {
    this.msgsSource.scan((arr: Message[], msgAction: MessageAction) => {
      return (msgAction.action === 'show') ?
        arr.concat(msgAction.msg) :
        arr.filter(msg => msg.id !== msgAction.msg.id);
    }, []).subscribe(this.messages);
  }

  show(text: string, type: MessageType, autoHideAfter: number = DEFAULT_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT) {
    const msg: Message = {
      id: '' + (this.msgIdx++),
      text: text,
      type: type
    };

    this.msgsSource.next({ action: 'show', msg: msg });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.msgsSource.next({ action: 'hide', msg: msg });
    }, autoHideAfter);
  }

  hide(id: string) {
    this.msgsSource.next({ action: 'hide', msg: { id: id } as Message });
  }

...
}
```